# "Global variable" in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony. I have an action that takes from the database a random object A and display it with Twig. It also shows a form. When the form is submit, it is "relaunching" the action and show another random object A.

How can I do to save my object A (which is a entity)? I thought about a global variable but I've read this is not very good)

I think it's all about the "symfony" logic that I don't have yet :)

PS : I'm french, sorry if my english is a bit bad :)

Thank you in advance,

Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want to show same object after form send you must add to the form hidden field that stores object id ( probably if you are using database it has primary key already and u can get it by $entity->getId() )

Comment: I didn't think to that (but to send the entire entity, which was more hard) ! Thanks !